# Conda's install program tells me that Pypdf2 is already installed, but I cannot import it in JupyterLab

Tags: installation, package, anaconda, pypdf

As I couldn't import it onto JupyterLab, I tried to re-install pypdf2 using

```
 conda install -c "conda-forge/label/broken" pypdf2
```

suggested by the userguide, and I got the message

> Solving environment:done. All requested packages already installed

pypdf2 is also in the conda list, but is still in the "not imported" list of the Anaconda Navigator. ...And I still get the msg "no module named pypdf2" in JupyterLab!

I'm using Windows 10.

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

I tried to re-install pypdf2 using conda install (as well as the install program of the anaconda navigator) and I got the msg that it was already installed. I cannot import it onto JupyterLab, though.
And the "installed/not installed" list of Anaconda Navigator still indicates the pypdf2 is **not** installed ...
A virtualenv is not a solution in the present context:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I decided to uninstall everything related to Python, Anaconda and any of their family members, and to reinstall Anaconda from the web - and it worked. I can now import PyPDF2.
So the problem was probably related to conflicting (and possibly old) versions of God knows what.